# Is there a list of Linux distros categorized by tags?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a source of information about Linux distros, classified by tags as one would with blog posts for example. Actually, the more metadata the better: 32/64-bit, Window Manager, even maybe Usage Scenario (music, graphics, etc.)

Ideally, I'm searching for an API of this database of Linux distros that can be queried and used in an application.

Anything like that exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia and Distrowatch provide a lot of information:

- [Linux distribution comparision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution_comparison)
- [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions) that shows several lists of Linux distributions. [Another link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions) shows comparison.